# Remove tags with one or more spaces without regex

Tags: jquery

How to remove tags with one or mor spaces without regex. (and with jQuery)

I can remove tags without spaces in this code. But I could not find the way to select tags with one or more spaces.

(I have read that is not a good idea to use regex with text. Is that correct? If so, all the other answers that I could find use regex)

```js
$('#tot').children().each(function() {
 if ($(this).text() == "") {
  $(this).remove();        
 }
});
```

```html
<div id="tot">
  <p>normal text</p>
  <p> </p>
  <div>  </div>
  <span></span>
  <small></small>
  <p>normal text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I have read that is not a good idea to use regex with text"* What exactly would you use them on then?

Comment: No, you've read that its not a good idea to parse *html* with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason not to use regular expressions for this, but if you really want to, you can use `$.trim` instead:

```
$('#tot').children().each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "") {
        $(this).remove();        
    }
});
```

That will remove elements that have no text at all, or that have only whitespace in them. Or the equivalent with a regular expression:

```
var rexWhitespace = /^\s*$/;
$('#tot').children().each(function() {
    if (rexWhitespace.test($(this).text())) {
        $(this).remove();        
    }
});
```

If you **only** want to remove elements with whitespace, leaving elements with no text at all alone, a regular expression is probably your best bet: You just change the `*` in the earlier one to a `+`:

```
var rexWhitespace = /^\s+$/;
// Change is here ------^
$('#tot').children().each(function() {
    if (rexWhitespace.test($(this).text())) {
        $(this).remove();        
    }
});
```

Comment: You put all the options and very well explained. I really appreciate. In this case is it better to use regular expresions or it does not matter?

Comment: @Nrc: I doubt it matters much either way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check for the presence of a specific character inside a string:

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf(' ') !== -1)
```

However, depending on your full requirements, a regular expression matching `[a-z0-9]` is probably a better solution than explicitly checking for the *thousands* of characters you probably don't want to allow in tags.

Comment: @Nrc There is no simple answer to that question. Regular expressions are a tool for matching patterns in text, you *might* choose to use them when you're trying to match a pattern in text.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// selecting the element with id="tot",
// finding its child elements,
// filtering that collection:
$('#tot').children().filter(function () {
    // $.trim() removes trailing, and leading, white-space
    // if the removal of that white-space leaves the
    // text of the element equal to an empty-string the
    // the condition evaluates to true, and the current
    // child element is retained in the collection:
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
// removing the retained elements (whose textContent is only
// white-space):
}).remove();
```

```js
$('#tot').children().filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
}).remove();
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tot">
  <p>normal text</p>
  <p>  </p>
  <div>  </div>
  <span>  </span>
  <small>     </small>
  <p>normal text</p>
</div>
```

Although this meets the requirement of removing empty elements, and elements whose entire `textContent` is white-space; rather than removing elements that contain a sequence of one or more white-space characters.

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: Why do you use filter and not each. Does it have any advantage?

Comment: Not so much, that I can think of; both `filter()` and `each()` (and almost every jQuery method that has an anonymous callback function) iterate over the supplied collection (returned by the selector) and can perform actions on each element in the collection. My use of `filter()` is, honestly, only a matter of personal approach; both approaches, however, work equally well (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: This works very well. This is new for me. I just want to understand and I am not sure about:  $.trim($(this).text()) This converts each peace to simple text and then removes the space. Is that correct?

Comment: Not precisely, but close: it retrieves the `textContent` of the element as a string; then it removes any leading white-space from the beginning and trailing white-space from the end (including tabs, carriage-returns/line-breaks).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't wanna use regex, I suggets you trying to test my function:

```
$('#tot').children().each(function() 
{
    var count = 0;
    var content = $(this).text();
    for(i=0; i<content.length; i++) 
    {
        if(content.charAt(i) == "")
        {
            count ++;
        }
        else break;       
    }
    if(count == content.length)
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```